# python: Error:[<__main__.class instance at 0x>]

Tags: python, function, class, instance

I wanna scrabble the APP's name on the app's website of Apple store and print it out on the terminal.

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class AppCrawler:
    def __init__(self,starting_url,depth):
        self.starting_url = starting_url
        self.depth = depth
        self.apps = []

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_app_from_link(self.starting_url)

    def get_app_from_link(self,link):
        start_page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(start_page.text)

        name =  tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        app = App(name)
        self.apps.append(app)

class App:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name:" + self.name)

crawler = AppCrawler('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731',0)
crawler.crawl()
################ print the list ##################################
print crawler.apps
################ print the element in the list ###################
for app in crawler.apps:
    print app
```

Here is what I get in the terminal:

```
[<__main__.App instance at 0x029C3EE0>]
AppName:Candy Crush Saga
```

My question is:

why the list print is *[<**main**.App instance at 0x029C3EE0>]*
and use the "*for in*" loop to print the element in the list is exactly right??

Comment: Inside the list, the `__repr__` method is called, not `__str__`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for app in crawler.apps:
    print str(app)
```

or implement

`__repr__` instead of `__str__`